# How to kill an app in iPhone using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

> In my app  I am having a continuous communication with TCP server , now if
>   server sends a command to close the app, i want to close the app completely
>   and when user taps the app again, it should start with Application launch method itself.

I have tried using exit(0) in the code, using this application goes into background.But it doesn't kill the app. How can i do that?

Comment: Why do you think that calling `exit` sends the app to the background? `exit` will definitely kill the app. But you are not supposed to call `exit` anyway. Your app may not be accepted by Apple if you do.

Comment: Note that Apple specifically disallows your app to kill itself/exit, and you will be rejected from the app store for this.

Comment: Per Apple "There is no API provided for gracefully terminating an iOS application." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html

Comment: This app is not for apple store. It will be used internal to my company.

Comment: I think the app remains in background because if i double click the home button, it shows me my app there. If its killed, it should not be there

Comment: @Nitya That's not true. The list of apps shown when you double-click the home button is a list of "recently-used-apps", not a "currently running list". Believe me, calling `exit` definitely terminates your app.

Comment: Did you actually try clicking on the app to launch it again to see if you saw your launch image or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way. Apple doesn't allow it. The solution is: Just accept the fact that you are unable to do this and work around that fact.

Comment: While this is true this doesn't address the question. The question claims that calling `exit(0)` puts the app in the background.

Comment: @rmaddy You are right. It actually kills the application.